# Modbus Register Map in C language ESp32

Tags: c, esp32, modbus

I am working with ESP32.. I want to communicate with external world with Modbus RTU.
The ESP32 would be the slave.
How can I create some modbus registers in c Language.
Any idea ?
It is just a simple table in C ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you confirm that we are discussing memory mapped registers? Do you have absolut addresses, sizes, maybe bitpositions? Info on readablity, writeability? Can you confirm that your question is only how to make those registers accessable from C? I.e. no help with the protocol needed or with when to read/write which values where.

Comment: We are discussing about create some registers inside the ESP32. Basically I have to receive some data from external microcontrollers or devices using modbus. The size of the information are clear ... maybe it is not clear to me the meaning of register.. The protocol is clear i have to create the modbus registers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did the same thing you want to do, not with ESP32, but it is the same.

Basically, you put all the variables you want accessible as a modbus register in a precise location, probably a struct.

For example

```
struct modbusmap_t {
  uint16_t    speed;    // this has modbus address 0
  unit16_t    cooler;   // ...and this address 1
  ...
} modbusregs;
```

Your device is a slave, so you will implement a server which receives the modbus commands. When a request for writing the register "N" is received, you can simply access that register with:

```
*((uint16_t *) &modbusregs + N) = requestvalue;
```

For reading, the same applies:

```
uint16result = *((uint16_t *) &modbusregs + N);
```

There other ways to do this, for example through a union.

To summarize, the key is to put all variables accessible as modbus registers in a known, ordered place, and use pointers or arrays to read/write them. For bits (modbus coils) some more trickery is necessary, but the idea is the same.

In this example, "modbus register 0" maps to the variable "speed" in your source. Modbus has no concept of sign, but you can manage this, using 2-complement, or adding an offset (32000 means 0 speed, 32010 means speed 10, 31990 means speed -10 and so on).

Comment: Or instead of icky pointer arithmetic place your struct inside a union between named members and an array of `uint16_t`, then use `modbusregs[N]`. C11 anonymous structs are excellent for this purpose.

Comment: That is (feel free to use this in your answer): `union modbusmap_t { struct { uint16_t speed; unit16_t cooler; ... }; uint16_t item[n]; } modbusregs;`

Comment: @Lundin yes, I mentioned that. With struct+pointers you can use clear names for the program, and a comment (modbus register number) aside each field - easy to maintain, at least at the beginning.

Comment: What if i want to create different modbus registers at different addresses ? Can you make an example ? Thanks a lot

Comment: @simonegaspa the example above already contains two different variables, *speed* and *cooler*, which map respectively to addresses 0 and 1. You can also create several structs or unions, each starting at different modbus registers: "if (modbusaddr >= 0x2000) { *point to another struct* }

Answer (score 0):

you can use this simple code and extend it as you desire
I defer it from esp32-idf source code

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef struct
{
    float holding_data0;
    float holding_data1;
    float holding_data2;
    float holding_data3;
    uint16_t test_regs[150];
    float holding_data4;
    float holding_data5;
    float holding_data6;
    float holding_data7;
} holding_reg_params_t;

extern holding_reg_params_t holding_reg_params;

#define HOLD_OFFSET(field) ((uint16_t)(offsetof(holding_reg_params_t, field) >> 1))
#define MB_REG_HOLDING_START_AREA0 (HOLD_OFFSET(holding_data0))
#define MB_REG_HOLDING_START_AREA1 (HOLD_OFFSET(holding_data4))

/**
 * @brief Type of Modbus parameter
 */
typedef enum
{
    MB_PARAM_HOLDING = 0x00, /*!< Modbus Holding register. */
    MB_PARAM_INPUT,          /*!< Modbus Input register. */
    MB_PARAM_COIL,           /*!< Modbus Coils. */
    MB_PARAM_DISCRETE,       /*!< Modbus Discrete bits. */
    MB_PARAM_COUNT,
    MB_PARAM_UNKNOWN = 0xFF
} mb_param_type_t;

/**
 * @brief Parameter storage area descriptor
 */
typedef struct
{
    uint16_t start_offset; /*!< Modbus start address for area descriptor */
    mb_param_type_t type;  /*!< Type of storage area descriptor */
    void *address;         /*!< Instance address for storage area descriptor */
    size_t size;           /*!< Instance size for area descriptor (bytes) */
} mb_register_area_descriptor_t;

mb_register_area_descriptor_t reg_area; // Modbus register area descriptor structure

int main()
{
    holding_reg_params_t holding_reg_params = {0};
    mb_register_area_descriptor_t reg_area; // Modbus register area descriptor structure

    holding_reg_params.holding_data0 = 1.34;
    holding_reg_params.holding_data1 = 2.56;
    holding_reg_params.holding_data2 = 3.78;
    holding_reg_params.holding_data3 = 4.90;

    holding_reg_params.holding_data4 = 5.67;
    holding_reg_params.holding_data5 = 6.78;
    holding_reg_params.holding_data6 = 7.79;
    holding_reg_params.holding_data7 = 8.80;

    reg_area.type = MB_PARAM_HOLDING;                             // Set type of register area
    reg_area.start_offset = MB_REG_HOLDING_START_AREA0;           // Offset of register area in Modbus protocol
    reg_area.address = (void *)&holding_reg_params.holding_data0; // Set pointer to storage instance
    // Set the size of register storage instance = 150 holding registers
    reg_area.size = (size_t)(HOLD_OFFSET(holding_data4) - HOLD_OFFSET(test_regs));
    *((float *)reg_area.address + reg_area.start_offset + 0) = 100;
    *((float *)reg_area.address + reg_area.start_offset + 1) = 200;
    *((float *)reg_area.address + reg_area.start_offset + 2) = 300;
    *((float *)reg_area.address + reg_area.start_offset + 3) = 400;
    *((uint16_t *)reg_area.address + reg_area.start_offset + 4) = 500;// be careful its wrong!
    // ESP_ERROR_CHECK(mbc_slave_set_descriptor(reg_area));
    reg_area.type = MB_PARAM_HOLDING;                             // Set type of register area
    reg_area.start_offset = MB_REG_HOLDING_START_AREA1;           // Offset of register area in Modbus protocol
    reg_area.address = (void *)&holding_reg_params.holding_data4; // Set pointer to storage instance
    reg_area.size = sizeof(float) << 2;                           // Set the size of register storage instance
    // ESP_ERROR_CHECK(mbc_slave_set_descriptor(reg_area));
    // getchar();
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).